# create and initialize database programmatically in odoo16CE

Tags: python, odoo

I have an API endpoint **`POST /database`** that is responsible for creating a new database. However, the current implementation seems to have performance issues, as it is slow. Here's the relevant code:

router.py.

```
@router.post("/",status_code=HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_env(data:Environment,env = Depends(master_env)):
    # Load the required models
    # Call the init() method on the module
    newEnv = env["api.env"].create(data.dict())
    return EnvironmentOutput.from_orm(newEnv)
```

model.py.

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
        vals.update({
            "email":self.env.context["email"]
        })
        env = super(Environment,self).create(vals)
        ret = exp_create_database(vals["name"], False, False, user_password=vals["name"], 
            login=vals["email"], country_code=None, phone=None)
        registry = odoo.registry(vals["name"]).check_signaling()
        with registry.manage_changes():
            with registry.cursor() as cr:
                e = odoo.api.Environment(cr, odoo.SUPERUSER_ID, {})
                m = e["ir.module.module"].search([('name', '=', "api")], limit=1)
                m.button_immediate_install()
        return env
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize this code and improve its performance. Any ideas or best practices to handle this scenario more efficiently would be greatly appreciated.